# Is there a way not to redirect people to a "thank you" page with Mailchimp?

Tags: list, mailchimp, mailing

I saw on the Mailchimp website that you can redirect the user to a custom thank you page when they subscribe to your mailing list, but that's not exactly what I want to do.

When a user subscribe to my mailing list, I want to hide the form and replace it with a thank you note directly on my page without any redirection. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by modifying the form action.

Change “subscribe/post” to “subscribe/post-json” …

```
<form action="...list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=...."
```

Add a submit handler to the form:

```
$("#subscribe-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    submitSubscribeForm($("#subscribe-form"));
});
```

Submit the form via AJAX ([Code referenced from Github here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rydama/mailchimp-ajax-signup/master/ajax-subscribe.html)):

```
function submitSubscribeForm($form, $resultElement) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "c",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            error: function(error){},

            success: function(data){
                if (data.result != "success") {
                    var message = data.msg || "Sorry. Unable to subscribe. Please try again later.";

                    if (data.msg && data.msg.indexOf("already subscribed") >= 0) {
                        message = "You're already subscribed. Thank you.";
                    }

                    $resultElement.html(message);

                } else {
```

And then write the code to display the signup confirmation

```
                    $resultElement.html("Thank you!<br>You must confirm the subscription in your inbox.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No dice for me - it still redirects to a blank page with the custom signup confirmation that you provided.

Comment: is it possible to do this without jquery ajax?