# How to prevent custom Mailchimp form from redirecting on submit?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, mailchimp

I have created a custom Mailchimp signup form on a webpage I am working on. Everything is fine, except I don't like how on submit, the form redirects to a new tab that has a message from Mailchimp stating you have joined the mail list. I am wondering if it is possible to prevent this redirect and maybe just display some thank you pop-up message at most.

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="subscribe" method="POST" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form2" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <label for="mail">SIGN UP FOR OUR MAILING LIST</label>

            <p class="form-status-text"></p>
            <!-- /.form-status-text -->

            <div class="form-controls no-border">
              <div class="form-group no-border">
                
                <input type="hidden" name="side" value="creativeagency" class="no-border" />
                <input type="email" id="mail" name="MERGE0" value="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" class="subscribe-field no-border" required data-validation-type="['presence', 'email']" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS') {this.value = '';}">  
         
              </div><!-- /.form-group -->
              
              <button type="submit" class="subscribe-btn" id="subscribe-button">
                <div class="subscribe-btn-svg">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 64.57" class="subscribe-btn-svg"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}</style></defs><title>Asset 9</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M4,36.28H66.34L44.89,57.74a4,4,0,1,0,5.66,5.66L78.83,35.11h0a4,4,0,0,0,.5-.61c.07-.1.11-.21.17-.31a3.85,3.85,0,0,0,.2-.37,3.65,3.65,0,0,0,.13-.41c0-.11.08-.22.1-.33a4,4,0,0,0,.08-.79h0a4,4,0,0,0-.08-.77c0-.12-.07-.23-.1-.35a3.58,3.58,0,0,0-.12-.4,4,4,0,0,0-.21-.4c-.05-.1-.1-.2-.16-.29a3.88,3.88,0,0,0-.5-.61L50.54,1.17a4,4,0,1,0-5.66,5.66L66.34,28.28H4a4,4,0,0,0,0,8Z"/></g></g></svg>
                </div>
              </button>
           </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with MailChimp but it looks to me like you should be able to send the POST data through a JavaScript function and avoid the redirect. But would this violate MailChimp's TOS?

Comment: Make it with ajax and jquery function

Comment: please show a [mcve] (including your JS code)

Comment: @ochi this form is from within a custom shopify store I am working on, as far as I can tell this is all the code that has to do with the form.

Comment: Do you have access to the mailchimp interface to modify the custom form? - if not, then there is nothing you can do as this is controlled by the generated JS code by the form (and invoked in the `action` attribute of the form)

Comment: @ochi this form was created completely from scratch, the only part that was not is the form action that you can see above. I believe that is used to point the entered email address to the right mailchimp list. Is there any way to simply block the submit button from opening a new tab?

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman I think that is also a viable solution however I know nothing about ajax. Would you be able to provide me with a little more insight possibly? Or point me in the right direction

Comment: I tried [this solution from another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834631/is-there-a-way-not-to-redirect-people-to-a-thank-you-page-with-mailchimp#_=_) with no success. Maybe you'll have more success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can make it with Ajax in jQuery, try something like this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var $form = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form2');
    if ( $form.length > 0 ) {
        $('form input[type="submit"]').bind('click', function ( event ) {
            if ( event ) event.preventDefault();
            register($form);
        });
    }
});

function register($form) {
    $.ajax({
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error       : function(err) { alert("Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later."); },
        success     : function(data) {
            if (data.result != "success") {
                // Something went wrong, do something to notify the user. maybe alert(data.msg);
            } else {
                // It worked, carry on...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this out later today. Where would I put the Mailchimp form action though?

Comment: @SpencerM. Just let your html. The script jquery get the method and action of your form. SO the ajax query go to the Mailchimp form action

Answer (score 0):

The problem i had here was  in two parts - first, the button infinitely pumped out the error message then mailchimp took over after one() had run and fired off the window

```
$( "#mc-embedded-subscribe-hp" ).one( "click", function(event) {
    let subscriptor = email.value;
    
    filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (filter.test(subscriptor)) {
        // Yay! valid
        // Mailchimp wil auto complete from here
    }
    else
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.newsletter-wrapper__column').append('<div class="subscription-error">Fill in your Email Address to receive Exclusive discounts</div>');
        window.stop();
    }
});
```